Remove a file attribute in turbo pascal
I am looking for a way to remove a file attribute in Turbo Pascal (DOS).
Set and Get is no problem, but I do not find a function that does this.

You use SET with an and not for the value you want to remove, IIRC. The typical use is to read the existing attributes, change them using Original := Original and not THEONETOREMOVE, and then SET to that new value.

Thanks, the right way.
The right way:
`var
attr : Word;
f : File of Char;
attr := attr and NOT archive;
assign(f, 'c:\test.TXT');
SetFAttr(f, attr); `

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Post answers as such, not as comments. Consider accepting answers to your questions, even from the past. Take the [tour].
